# Error on Eclipse Android App

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest, eclipse-juno

**Please could somebody help me locate my issue here...**

```
[2013-07-15 10:29:36 - Database demo] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.AssentApp.V100/com.AssentApp.V100 }
[2013-07-15 10:29:36 - Database demo] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-07-15 10:29:39 - Database demo] Starting activity com.AssentApp.V100 on device emulator-5554
[2013-07-15 10:29:40 - Database demo] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-07-15 10:29:43 - Database demo] Starting activity com.AssentApp.V100 on device emulator-5554
[2013-07-15 10:29:45 - Database demo] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-07-15 10:29:48 - Database demo] Starting activity com.AssentApp.V100 on device emulator-5554
[2013-07-15 10:29:49 - Database demo] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.AssentApp.V100/com.AssentApp.V100 }
[2013-07-15 10:29:49 - Database demo] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2013-07-15 10:29:49 - Database demo] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.AssentApp.V100/com.AssentApp.V100} does not exist.
```

I am presuming I have names something incorrectly, potentially in my Manifext xml. Or perhaps elsewhere...

Looking at the above code, I see that it launches the package on the emulator, and then is **unable to find** the *activity class com.AssentApp.V100* . I think I will have re-names a field wrong somewhere, **below is my main.xml for inspection**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"

>
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
/>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="70dp"

>
</FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Here is my manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.AssentApp.V100"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.AssentApp.V100"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddEmployee"
        android:label="Add Employee" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GridList"
        android:label="Employees" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PhotoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photo" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AudioRecordTest"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_audio_record_test" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

</manifest>
```

I think the issue may come with the line `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` but this is just speculating...

This has all stemmed from trying to rename the SCR folders. Not to others... Don't try this unless you know what you are doing. Or more importantly, take a backup first !

Comment: post your .java code for that activity

Comment: Your main activity name and manifest package are the same. Or your activity name is incorrect or package name in manifest file. Try edit second line in manifest to this <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.AssentApp"

Comment: close enough... :) it was my `activity
            android:name=` which wasn't my correct java file for my main.xml... Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be with your build / run configuration . Please check the "Deploy application" checkbox in the Run/Debug Configuration screen, under the General tab.

Comment: I don't have a General Tab... Using Eclipse Juno - `Debug As > Debug Configurations > Adroid, Target or Common`

Comment: May be you should try to uninstall your app from Mobile

Answer (score 0):

try to test in another emulator.. or restart eclipse then check